# Errors with numpy unwrap when the using long arrays

Tags: python, numpy, unwrap

I am trying to use the function `numpy.unwrap` to correct some phase

I have long vector with 2678399 records which contains the difference in radians between 2 angles. The array contains nan values although I think is not relevant as unwrap is applied to each record independently.

When I applied unwrap, by the 400 record generates nan values in the rest of the array

If I apply np.unwrap to just one slice of the original array works fine.

Is that a possible bug in this function?

```
d90dif=(df2['d90']-df2['d90avg'])*(np.pi/180)#difference between two angles in radians
df2['d90dif']=np.unwrap(d90dif.values)#unwrap to the array to create new column
```

## just to explain the problem

```
d90dif[700:705]#angle difference for some records
2013-01-01 00:11:41    0.087808
2013-01-01 00:11:42    0.052901
2013-01-01 00:11:43    0.000541
2013-01-01 00:11:44    0.087808
2013-01-01 00:11:45    0.017995
dtype: float64

df2['d90dif'][700:705]#results with unwrap for these records
2013-01-01 00:11:41   NaN
2013-01-01 00:11:42   NaN
2013-01-01 00:11:43   NaN
2013-01-01 00:11:44   NaN
2013-01-01 00:11:45   NaN
Name: d90dif, dtype: float64
```

## now I repeat the process with a small array

```
test=d90dif[700:705]
2013-01-01 00:11:41    0.087808
2013-01-01 00:11:42    0.052901
2013-01-01 00:11:43    0.000541
2013-01-01 00:11:44    0.087808
2013-01-01 00:11:45    0.017995
dtype: float64

unw=np.unwrap(test.values)
array([ 0.08780774,  0.05290116,  0.00054128,  0.08780774,  0.01799457])
```

Now it is ok. If I do it with a dataframe input in unwrap() works fine as well

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [documentation of unwrap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html), it seems that NaN would have an effect since the function is looking at differences of adjacent elements to detect jumps in the phase.

Comment: Ok. Then makes sense. But I know that the corresponding function in Matlab does not create such a problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the nan values play an important role

```
test

2013-01-01 00:11:41    0.087808
2013-01-01 00:11:42    0.052901
2013-01-01 00:11:43    0.000541
2013-01-01 00:11:44         NaN
2013-01-01 00:11:45    0.017995
dtype: float64
```

If there is nan in the column, from there everything becomes a nan

```
np.unwrap(test)

array([ 0.08780774,  0.05290116,  0.00054128,         nan,         nan])
```

I would say this is a bug but...