# Numpy unwrap ignoring NaN

Tags: python, numpy, unwrap

I have a long numpy array with wind direction records, and I'm trying to use numpy's `unwrap` before running an algorithm to detect jumps in the data. The data contains NaNs, and numpy seems unable to process this. As soon as one NaN is encountered, all following data points returned by `unwrap` are also converted to NaNs. Is there a way around this?

I think my question boils down to the same question as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894896/errors-with-numpy-unwrap-when-the-using-long-arrays), but there it's only concluded that the error is related to NaNs in the data and no solution is offered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the NaNs, the simplest solution is to mask out the NaNs before passing the array to `unwrap` and use the same mask to write the result back:

```
a[~np.isnan(a)] = np.unwrap(a[~np.isnan(a)])
```

If you want to keep the original array, use `np.copy`:

```
b = np.copy(a)
b[~np.isnan(b)] = np.unwrap(b[~np.isnan(b)])
```